# AWS Amplify build failing - Failed to get profile: Profile configuration is missing for: amplify

Tags: aws-amplify

I have an AWS-Amplify project that had been building without a problem but is now failing.

```
# Starting phase: build
2021-11-20T00:40:02.506Z [INFO]: [31mFailed to get profile: Profile configuration is missing for: amplify[39m
2021-11-20T00:40:02.564Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2021-11-20T00:40:02.564Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2021-11-20T00:40:02.564Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2021-11-20T00:40:02.565Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

The problem seemed to start after I made an error doing a pull request (in the wrong direction!), however, the problem has persisted despite reverting back to an earlier commit.

I have also ensured all the Amplify code is up to date `amplify pull`, as well as trying `amplify configure` and `amplify init` on my development machine.

Other posts that describe problems with 'Profile Configuration' seem to be related to the development machine and setting up the CLI. This failure is happening when I try to build on AWS using continuous deploys, building locally works fine.

Answer (score 0):

so i got it to work.

Just delete the aws-exports.json and the amplify folder.
Then run the command from amplify which is something like:
amplify pull --appId XXXXXXXXXXX --envName dev

After a few mins, it will prompt you to select:
AWS PROFILE
AWS KEYS

select AWS KEYS
enter credentials for a programmatic user and it should be fine